# Ubuntu 16 and a group-shared folder with good directory security

Tags: ubuntu

I'm setting up btsync (for code sharing between servers) in Ubuntu 16 and trying to make it use a group shared folder. Here's the ps:

> btsync   27420  0.1  0.4 572916 17632 ?        Ssl  01:21   1:07
> /usr/bin/btsync --config /etc/btsync/config.json

I'm pointing the downloading to a specific folder. It's this:

> drwxrws---+  2 cente fileserver 4096 Mar 14 01:31 storage/

...that is inside this:

> drwxr-xr-x   3 root fileserver  4096 Mar  9 12:53 media/

(so the final destination is /media/storage)

```
cente@server:/$ getfacl /media/storage getfacl: Removing leading '/'
 from absolute path names
  file: media/storage
  owner: cente
  group: fileserver
  flags: -s- user::rwx group::rwx other::rwx default:user::rwx default:group::rwx default:group:fileserver:rwx default:mask::rwx
 default:other::---
```

When using this setting, the ui complains about not being able to create a folder inside. I chmod /media/storage to 777 and a folder is now able to be created within the ui. I don't want to use 777 if I can help it.

> $ groups btsync
>
> btsync : btsync fileserver

I tried changing the umask to 007 as well, no dice. How can I make this work while keeping the system as secure as possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bittorrent-sync-to-synchronize-directories-in-ubuntu-12-04), it may be a case of needing to adjust the contents within `/media/storage/`.

The guide recommends doing the following:

```
sudo mkdir shared_folder
sudo chown root:btsync shared_folder
sudo chmod 2775 shared_folder
sudo usermod -a -G btsync your_user
```

Where `shared_folder` is your `/media/storage`, and `your_user` is the user populating files into `/media/storage`.

Although I don't see why your approach shouldn't work, the guide itself seems somewhat insistent that things should be moved to the ownership of btsync's group, rather than the btsync user being added to another group.

I am not really familiar with btsync, but there are other programmes I can think of that only check the effective group id of a process, but not any supplementary groups (for a bit of background on that, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/gid-current-primary-supplementary-effective-and-real-group-ids).

This would be consistent with your symptoms: btsync seems to be evaluating to `other`, rather than `group`, which is why 770 does not work, but 777 does.

So, I rather sounds as though you might have to make things work with btsync in this case, rather than have btsync work with your setup. 
In other words, change all group ownership from `fileserver` to `btsync`, and adjust the user(s) writing data to your share to have btsync as a supplementary group.